# Retrieve position of cities Google Map API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I want to retrieve the latitude and longitude of every city in the world with Google map.
I use [a Google Fusion table](http://pastie.org/private/huqusuz9etjr5xpbcylgag):

```
function requestCities()
{
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    var url = ['https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?'];
    url.push('sql=');
    //var query = 'SELECT CITY_NAME, geometry, POP_RANK, STATUS FROM ' + '1jmboG7oPaWTAUKubEl__YMVvkIkmhKTxxfD3wNo' + " WHERE 'CNTRY_NAME' = '"+ focusedCountry +"'";
    var query = 'SELECT CITY_NAME, geometry, POP_RANK, STATUS, FIPS_CNTRY, GMI_ADMIN FROM ' + '1ld4KaHF-E6UbFoN_VdCUp_s0_liEE7poZ7v4OmU' + " WHERE 'POP_RANK' \< 5";
    //var query = 'SELECT CITY_NAME, geometry, POP_RANK, STATUS FROM ' + '1jmboG7oPaWTAUKubEl__YMVvkIkmhKTxxfD3wNo';

    var encodedQuery = encodeURIComponent(query);
    url.push(encodedQuery);
    url.push('&callback=setCities');
    url.push('&key=AIzaSyACrx-nlt1KZ8cDNpsvW_FW8JPEKfbpF8g');
    script.src = url.join('');
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    body.appendChild(script);
}
```

And inside my callback function I [try to add a marker on each city](http://pastie.org/private/rlqcsxeyjp7fpy5rfborug):

```
function setCities(data)
{
    var rows = data['rows'];
    console.log(rows[0]);

    var nbInfobox = document.getElementById("infobox-wrapper").getElementsByTagName("div").length;

    for (var i in rows)
    {
        var name = rows[i][0];
        var pop_rank = rows[i][2];
        var status = rows[i][3];
        //var countryCode = rows[i][4];
        var cityCode = rows[i][5];
        var countryCode = cityCode.substring(0,2);
        var capital = eval(status[0] == "N");

        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(rows[i][1]['geometry']['coordinates'][1], rows[i][1]['geometry']['coordinates'][0]);

        var image = 'img/marker_'+ pop_rank+ '.png';
        if (capital)
        {
            var image = 'img/marker_capital.png';
            pop_rank = 0;
        }

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
            {
                position: myLatlng,
                title: name,
                zIndex: 7 - pop_rank,
                icon: image
            });


        //Create infobox for selected cities
        $("#infobox-wrapper").append("<div id=\"infobox" + nbInfobox + "\" class=\"infoboxcountry\" />");

        var info = new InfoBox({
            content: document.getElementById("infobox" + nbInfobox),
            position: marker.getPosition(),
            disableAutoPan: true,
            pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, 0),
            zIndex: 0,
            closeBoxURL: ""
        });

        $("#infobox" + nbInfobox).html(marker.getTitle());

        var city = new City(i, marker, info, pop_rank, countryCode, cityCode);

        overlays.cities.push(city);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            cityClick(this);
        });

        ++nbInfobox;
    }

}
```

The result from my query is an array with the all cities in the world like this:

```
 ["Lima", "<Point><coordinates>", "1", "National and provincial capital", "PE", "PER-LIM"]
```

But I always get this error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'coordinates' of undefined
```

I have no clue about how to get the coordinate from my array var row. If someone knows, thanks for your help.

Comment: @geocodezip I can say the same thing for you, I gave you an access to reproduce the exact error online but you can't because of Facebook login and you said "Ask someone else for help" So why arguing now with my post??

Comment: instead of teaching users what they have to do, you better set the focus on your problem. At the moment when you've written your question it should have been obvious to you that `"<Point><coordinates>"` is not the expected response, it's a string and not an object, so trying to fetch `['geometry']['coordinates']` must fail on this string. Keeping this in mind your short and minimal question(as requested  by geocodezip in the deleted question) should have been "why did I not get the expected response from the table". Posting more irrelevant code didn't make your question better.

Comment: @Dr.Molle So funny ..... You didn't find the answer too and it wasn't obvious for you aswell! Why are you here to defend other people, I'm not teaching anyone here I just came with a problem, that's all folks!

Comment: Well, you must be right: *Note that @Dr. Molle answered first.. we both arrived at a similar conclusion, but I spent too much time looking at the problem to not post the answer. –  p e p 1 hour ago*  **I found the answer, but maybe you've lost something?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with your data source. Looking at your script, you are doing a `select ...  from 1ld4KaHF-E6UbFoN_VdCUp_s0_liEE7poZ7v4OmU`.  So I searched for that and found the fusion table, [Copy of World Cities.csv](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1ld4KaHF-E6UbFoN_VdCUp_s0_liEE7poZ7v4OmU#rows%3aid=1). Looking at the info, I found it was copied from [this table (1TJk4Fh8AU5IIhMDmvJOhcAOu9I5EB6xu9uKxI30)](http://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1TJk4Fh8AU5IIhMDmvJOhcAOu9I5EB6xu9uKxI30). I made a JSFiddle and put a debugger in the callback function.  When the script was selecting from the table that you have in your question,  the `geometry` property is undefined because `rows[i][1]` is not JSON, but rather is always the malformed XML `"<Point><coordinates>"` no matter what the city is.  However, if you switch your script to select from `1TJk4Fh8AU5IIhMDmvJOhcAOu9I5EB6xu9uKxI30` (the original fusion table, not the copy you are using) instead, the following code gives you the coordinates just fine: `rows[i][1]['geometry']['coordinates'][1]`. So, in `requestCities`, use the following query instead of what you have:

```
var query = 'SELECT CITY_NAME, geometry, POP_RANK, STATUS, FIPS_CNTRY, GMI_ADMIN FROM ' + '1TJk4Fh8AU5IIhMDmvJOhcAOu9I5EB6xu9uKxI30' + " WHERE 'POP_RANK' \< 5";
```

Comment: Note that @Dr. Molle answered first.. we both arrived at a similar conclusion, but I spent too much time looking at the problem to not post the answer.

Comment: @geocodezip Instead of only editing and putting -1 at every post you see, you should sometimes sit back and let the people answer when they knows! With the same topic, I got +5 and a good answer from @p e p.

Comment: @Katcha YOU should sit back and relax instead of getting angry at the most helpful users on this topic! That said, if you are getting downvotes, there usually is a reason. Work on it and you will eventually get upvotes. Take it easy!

Answer (score 2):

As it seems there is something wrong with the data in this table.

When I take a look at [https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1ld4KaHF-E6UbFoN_VdCUp_s0_liEE7poZ7v4OmU&pli=1#map:id=3](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1ld4KaHF-E6UbFoN_VdCUp_s0_liEE7poZ7v4OmU&pli=1#map%3aid=3) there are no markers on the map, somehow the `geometry` has not been recognized correctly.

e.g. the particular row should look like this:

```
["Lima",{"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-77.0450036007242,-12.0819959357647]}},"1","National and provincial capital","PE","PER-LIM"]
```

as you see the 2nd column differs from your response `<Point><coordinates>`

I can't tell you why this happens, maybe because of the `NaN` that is used in  the KML of geometry for the altitude:

```
<Point><coordinates>-77.0450036007242,-12.0819959357647,NaN</coordinates></Point>
```

However, for testing I made a copy of the table, and by  magic the copy seems to work correctly:

[https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1re5M5ZjS7oUTux3ng538gQZMP3ralKTxPtfZJplB#map:id=3](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1re5M5ZjS7oUTux3ng538gQZMP3ralKTxPtfZJplB#map%3aid=3)

So you may try the same...create a copy of the table(don't use my copy, I will delete the table some day)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will check that now, maybe I need to fetch the data from another fusion table iD.